# Why are search results slow to display?

Tags: search, performance

We have a single Windows Server 2008 64bit with SQL 2008 R2 installation for SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

I've enabled the search services  so  the  search query is returning results. However the time it takes to resolve is too long, anywhere from 30 seconds to 2 minutes. The collection is small - about 10 team sites with a few documents for testing. We expect search results to take about 2 seconds but cannot figure out what could cause the query or index to bottleneck or perform so poorly.

Any thoughts? We have no add-ons, just out of the box features.

1/14/2011:
the increamental crawl timer is set for 60 minutes
 no error founded on the sharepoint logs.
 did see this error message on the windows log  evet id 6398:
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Monitoring.TraceDiagnosticsProvider (ID 7c7174d4-19bf-43b8-9b92-ac3ab020e7d7) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9931505. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

update 1/17/2011:
Can People  that have  sharepoint2010 and sql 2008 deployed on the same virtual single  server enviroment  post the  time it takes to get results from a search and what your perceive index load may be.  please I just need to know if this issue is unique or just accepted by users.

Answer (score 1):

Poor performance can be the result of your incremental crawl being configured with too short of a gap between crawls, resulting in the crawler running virtually all the time. Do you notice any crawl warnings or errors, or any other errors in the Windows or SharePoint logs?

Comment: I posted what i could find above.

Comment: Another piece of data is that this install is virualizated on hyper-V . I also have a wss 3.0 virtualized guest on the same server  yet the sites and search engine are performing well, search results in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Applied sharepoint updates cumulative  kb2459257 (014.0.5130.5002) that did not help.

Ended up  having to patch the server 2008 r2  with  all current updates, So I don't know which one corrected the problem as there are 66 updates that got appiled.

but now the search  result  return  in 2-5 seconds.

Oh joy.